# Passing per-object shader parameters in Graphics.Blit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have an outline shader passed to Graphics.Blit that draws outlines in a certain color. **How would I make some objects take a different outline color?** I'm imagining something about passing a uniform to that object's shader and somehow referencing that in my outline shader, but i'm not sure how!

```
void Start () {
    edgeDetectMaterial = new Material (Shader.Find ("Hidden/EdgeDetectColors"));
    edgeDetectMaterial.SetVector ("_Color", Color.red);
}

void OnRenderImage (RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination) {
    Graphics.Blit (source, destination, edgeDetectMaterial);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this a while ago, so sorry for the bad coding, and response
The way I did it last time was using command buffer, in which you get an object that contains the info of the color you want to outline and the reference to the renderers.

```
public class OutlineObj
{
    public Color outlineColor;
    private Color currentColor;
    public Color targetColor;
    public float speed;
    public Renderer[] renderers;
    public void Outline ()
    {
        currentColor = targetColor;
    }
}
```

As for the main shader doing the outline, you just need to get the vertex of the object (the camera) and set the Outline color as a global variable.

```
v2f vert (appdata v)
{
    v2f o;
    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);
    return o;
}

fixed4 _OutlineColor;

fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    return _OutlineColor;
}
```

Then a controller where you can register the objects and build a command buffer, I can't remember all of it, but pretty much you gotta clear the command buffer, get the render Texture before image effects, then you set a render target, clear the targets and set the colors you want with

```
public class OutlineController
{
    private CommandBuffer buffer;
    public List<OutlineObj> registerObjects;    

    private void Awake ()
    {
        //GetAll the shaders and their ID
        //Add buffer to camera as before image effects.
    }

    public void Register (OutlineObj obj)
    {
        //register the object
        registerObjects.Add(obj);
    }

private void BuildCommandBuffer ()
{
    //Clear command buffer
    //Get the RT and set the render target
    //Per every object that wants an outline add their color and renders
    foreach (OutlineObj obj in registerObjects)
    {
        buffer.SetGlobalColor (outlieColor, obj.currentColor);
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.renderers.Length; ++i)
        {
            buffer.DrawRenderer(obj.renderers[i], controllerMat);
        }
    }
    //Set the renderPassTexture on the buffers blit
}
    private void Update ()
    {
        BuildCommandBuffer ();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps, look into how to do composite outlines using command buffers.